# toggle input field editable

Tags: css, input, checkbox, toggle

I would like to make form fields editable only after clicking a button, without Javascript. In the first state (readonly) I wanted to make the frame invisible and set the pointer events to "none". The button is supposed to be a checkbox, but there is no effect on the input fields, unlike the test frame below.

```css
label.toggle {color:white; background: darkred;padding: 0.1rem .3rem;border-radius: 0.5rem;}
.visually-hidden {position: absolute;left: -100vw;}

.toggle_edit {color:black;   border:1px solid #FFFFFF;}
#toggle:checked ~ .toggle_edit {color:darkred; border:1px solid #000000;}
                  input.toggle_edit {color:black; border:1px solid #FFFFFF;}
#toggle:checked ~ input.toggle_edit {color:darkred;  border:1px solid #000000; pointer-events: none;}
```

```html
<div> <!-- toggle -->
  <label class="toggle" for="toggle">bearbeiten</label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="visually-hidden">
  <table>
    <form action="functions/edit.php" method="post" target="editframe"> 
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="toggle_edit" name="justus" value="Justus" size="30" maxlength="50" ></td>
      </tr> 
      <input type="Submit" name="absenden" value="absenden"></form>
  </table>
  <div class="toggle_edit">Testframe</div> 
</div> <!-- toggle -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the `~` (the "general sibling combinator") selects **sibling** elements that follow the element before the `~` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

In your example, the `input.toggle_edit` isn't a sibling ("Geschwister") of the checkbox. Instead its ancestor, the `table`, is the sibling. Therefore you have to add the `table` as indicated in the CSS below in the line `#toggle:checked~table input.toggle_edit`.

Also I understand that you want the `input` to be editable if the checkbox is checked. Your code seems to want to do the opposite. This is why I've replaced `pointer-events: none` with `pointer-events:auto` and added the `pointer-events:none` later on.

```
<div> <!-- toggle -->
  <label class="toggle" for="toggle">bearbeiten</label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="visually-hidden">
  <table>
    <form action="functions/edit.php" method="post" target="editframe"> 
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="toggle_edit" name="justus" value="Justus" size="30" maxlength="50" ></td>
      </tr> 
      <input type="Submit" name="absenden" value="absenden"></form>
  </table>
  <div class="testframe">Testframe</div> 
</div> <!-- toggle -->
```

```
label.toggle {
  color: white;
  background: darkred;
  padding: 0.1rem .3rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

.toggle_edit {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle_edit {
  color: darkred;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

input.toggle_edit {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

/* main problem was the missing table on the next line*/
#toggle:checked~table input.toggle_edit {
  color: darkred;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.toggle_edit {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#toggle:checked~table~.testframe {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but especially for the good explanation. Now not only does my code work, but I understand why.